# How to make global all variables starting with this expression

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a function and want to declare all as global all variables starting with $lang_ because so far I have something like this:

```
function {
 global $lang_welcome;
 global $lang_hello;
 global $lang_footer;
 ...

}
```

but I have way to many variables like this so declaring one by one is out of the question. Any workarounds?

Comment: You can use an array to store the names and loop it to declare.

Comment: I had considered that but I would need to change all declared variables and edit them one by one into an array.

Comment: Uhhh... _don't_. Write a class. Then use that class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to reach, but if all variables are declared outside the function and you want gain access to them inside, you can do something like this:

```
function func(&$vars) {

    foreach ($vars as $name => $var) {
        if (strpos($name, 'lang') === 0) {
            global ${$name};
        }
    }

    echo $lang_a;
    echo $lang_b;
}

$lang_a = 'lang_a';
$lang_b = 'lang_b';

$vars = get_defined_vars();

func($vars);
```

this is dirty way, but I believe it may provide your goal.